# Querying the value of a specific key in a Mongodb document with multiple objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to Node.js and I am trying to set up a website with a server, where users are able to enter a code. The server then checks if the specific code exists in a MongoDB database. If that is true, the server will redirect the user and renders a new page, containing information originating from other values in that same object.

I am able to render a page with a templating engine, and I am also able to successfully establish a connection with the MongoDB Atlas database. All objects are located as an array in one document on the server. I seem lost on making a successful query to the database.

The schema for the user is as following:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    token: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        max: 8
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema)
```

I have uploaded all tokens and names as a JSON file with the help of a Mongo GUI. All entries in the database are a collection objects (https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEWup.png)

I've tried the following queries (with no luck);

```
User.find({ token: req.body.token })
    .then(user => {
    if(user.token == req.body.token) {
        console.log('Succesful query!')
        res.redirect('/nextpage')
    } else {
            res.redirect('/')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it findOne() instead find()

```
User.findOne({ token: req.body.token })
        .then(user => {
        if(user.token == req.body.token) {
            console.log('Succesful query!')
            res.redirect('/nextpage')
        } else {
                res.redirect('/')
        }
    })
```